# Empty header nodes when webscraping Fox News site

Tags: r, web-scraping, xml2

I'm writing a small sentiment analysis program in R for various news sites, and Fox News is giving me some trouble when I try to access their "Trending" news site at https://www.foxnews.com/trending/.

I'm using the excellent xml2 package to read the webpage, then attempting to access the nodes containing the article titles. From Chrome's "Inspect" feature, I can see that these are all tagged as `<h3>` nodes, so I'd like to access all h3 nodes and grab their information. Code to do this is shown below:

```r
library(xml2)
webpage <- "https://www.foxnews.com/trending/"
web_raw <- read_html(webpage)
node <- '//h3'
xml_find_all(web_raw, xpath = node)
# OUTPUT:
# {xml_nodeset (11)}
# [1] <h3></h3>
# [2] <h3></h3>
# [3] <h3></h3>
# ...[cont.]
```

However, the nodes returned are all empty (`<h3></h3>`), although the number of h3 nodes returned matches up with what I'd expect.

Again using Chrome's Inspect feature to copy the XPath to one such h3 node returns the following:

```
//*[@id="id_Helicopter"]/a/div[2]/h3
```

which also fails to return the expected titles, instead producing a completely empty nodeset.

I then tried to manually construct the path, but I can only get a certain number of nodes deep before it starts returning empty nodes again:

```r
# This is the path to the last complete node returned
path <- '/html/body/div/div[@id="wrapper"]/div[@id="main"]/div/div[@class="module articles"]/div[@class="list"]'
# OUTPUT:
# {xml_nodeset (1)}
# [1] <div class="list">\n\t\t\t\t\t<div id="filter">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t... [cont.]

# When I access the unordered list one level deeper, it comes up empty
path <- '/html/body/div/div[@id="wrapper"]/div[@id="main"]/div/div[@class="module articles"]/div[@class="list"]/ul'
# OUTPUT:
# {xml_nodeset (1)}
# [1] <ul></ul>\n
```

#### Other notes:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49336132/empty-nodes-when-scraping-links-with-rvest-in-r) asks about a similar problem, where the problem was created by a script that rendered more of the webpage as the user scrolled through - however, their solution doesn't work for me because I can't expand the webpage manually.

Functional, comparable code for the New York Times is shown below. The only difference is that the NYT stores its titles in h1 tags instead of h3.

```r
library(xml2)
webpage <- "https://www.nytimes.com/trending/"
web_raw <- read_html(webpage)
node <- "//h1"
xml_find_all(web_raw, xpath = node)
# OUTPUT:
# {xml_nodeset (14)}
# [1] <h1 class="css-1om64mr">Trending</h1>\n
# [2] <h1>Justice Dept. Agrees to Turn Over Key Mueller Evidence to House</h1>
# [3] <h1>Elizabeth Warren Has Lots of Plans. Together, They Would Remake the Economy.</h1>
# ...[cont.]
```

**Any advice to help work around what's happening?**

Comment: Not sure if this helps you but if you just make a `get` `request` to https://www.foxnews.com/feeds/trending/all/feed/json?callback=articles you will get back a `JSON` response, which contains some information. It also gives you the url to the actual article (which you could `request` to gather further information). Always make sure to inspect all the `requests` being made. A lot of the time there is a better way to gather the data than parsing `HTML`.

Comment: I am not able to access the websites mentioned in your question.